# How the public key can be ensured being from sender in the digital signature security model?

Tags: security, digital-signature, public-key

I read an article about digital signature ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)) and have question as follows.

Let's say Alice wants to send a message to Bob. She need to let Bob know the message is from her. So she encrypted the hashed message with her private key into a certificate. Then Bob can decrypted the message with public key when receiving it. Bob can know it is from Alice if the hash code of the message matches the hash code which is decrypted from certificate. Here we have the assumption that Bob already knows the public key. What if the transmission of public key is already attacked? Bob might use the wrong public key to decrypt the wrong message and get that the message if from Alice. Is there any protocal or policy to avoid the attack against public key? And shall we？

Comment: Might be better on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the authenticity of public keys is a key component of applied cryptography. I can issue a public key that says "I am the website of your bank, trust me", but you shouldn't really trust it. Different schemes have been developed to establish authentication of public keys. One approach is the [web of trust model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) in PGP and GnuPG, others are [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29). One of the main difference between these approaches is where you place your trust. I provide a **simplified description** only, you have to read about them to learn about the exact details (you wouldn't base your security on an extremely short summary, would you?).

In the **web of trust** there are some people who you trust, and you (ideally) verified their public keys personally. You can trust other public keys if they have been signed by several people bearing your initial trust. Using these trusted individuals you can check more and more keys.

In **PKI** (Personal Key Infrastructure) you trust several **Certificate Authorities** (CAs) and accept their public keys. You trust them that they thoroughly check the identity of key holders before signing their public keys. The combination of public key + signature from a CA (and some other data) forms a **certificate**. The PKI is used in [SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), it is the underlying infrastructure of the secure web. You use it when you read your mail on a web interface, when you do online banking, etc. If a [CA is compromised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Subversion_of_CA), then every certificate signed by the CA will be come insecure.

In **Kerberos** is designed for computer networks and the **key server** is the single point of trust. It provides mutual authentication and a unique symmetric encryption key for clients and servers. The key server checks the identity of clients by a secret shared only between the key server and the client. Kereberos is used, for example, in Windows, AFS, Grid computing.

Answer (score 0):

your answer gave me much of insight into the question. And also, I would like to put the wikipedia link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Security here. Coz there is one stentence in the article solve my question "who certificate the Certificate Authority"

> This is an example of a self-signed certificate, as the issuer and subject are the same. There's no way to verify this certificate except by checking it against itself; instead, these top-level certificates are manually stored by web browsers. Thawte is one of the root certificate authorities recognized by both Microsoft and Netscape. This certificate comes with the web browser and is trusted by default.

Just in case some one has the same question.